# Need Help on KQL with Over Partitions

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to KQL and need your help and suggestion on below query.

I have data like below:

```
Date         Identity  totalIngressInGB
2021-10-10     x            10
2021-10-10     y            20
2021-10-10     z            30
2021-10-10     q            10
2021-10-11     x            11
2021-10-11     y            22
2021-10-11     z            33
2021-10-11     p            10
2021-10-11     q            5
```

I want to print like below:

- Trying to print current day value(**totalIngressInGB_c**) and previous day value(**totalIngressInGB_p**) and then difference.
- Printing only positive values in **diffInGB** column as I need only incremental values.

```
Date          Identity  totalIngressInGB_c totalIngressInGB_p diffInGB
2021-10-11       X           11                  10              1
2021-10-11       y           22                  20              2
2021-10-11       z           33                  30              3
2021-10-11       p           10                  0               10
```

Below is code in Hive SQL and Query results from our actual database, Now data is in ADX where I need to print same in KQL. I have tried in many ways not able to reach exact results like below in KQL.

[image: Below is code in Hive SQL and Query results from our actual database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `prev()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction

```
table(Date:datetime, Identity :string, totalIngressInGB:long)
[
    datetime(2021-10-10), 'x', 10,
    datetime(2021-10-10), 'y', 20,
    datetime(2021-10-10), 'z', 30,
    datetime(2021-10-10), 'q', 10,
    datetime(2021-10-11), 'x', 11,
    datetime(2021-10-11), 'y', 22,
    datetime(2021-10-11), 'z', 33,
    datetime(2021-10-11), 'p', 10,
    datetime(2021-10-11), 'q', 5,
]
| order by Identity asc, Date asc 
| project Date, Identity, totalIngressInGB_c = totalIngressInGB,
          totalIngressInGB_p = case(prev(Identity) == Identity, prev(totalIngressInGB),
                                    isempty(prev(Identity)), 0,
                                    long(null))
| extend diff = totalIngressInGB_c - totalIngressInGB_p
| where diff > 0
```